# MVC Razor setting datetime does not display date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core, datepicker, editorformodel

I would like to set the value based on a Tempdata but it is not showing .
My TempData value stored is '2012-09-28'. I tested both below but it is not displaying in the datepicker:

**Model.cs**

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<DateTime> bookDate{ get; set; }
```

**MyPage.cshtml**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.myModel.bookDate, new { @Value = "2012-09-28", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.myModel.bookDate, new { @Value =  TempData["myDate"], htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@Html.EditorFor`,the value of myModel.bookDate will cover `@Value = "2012-09-28"`.You can try to do like this:

```
<input id="myModel.bookDate" name="myModel.bookDate" value=@TempData["myDate"] class="form-control" type="date"/>
```